# How do I increase the size of Font Awesome icons in Wordpress CSS

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, font-size

How do I increase the size of Font Awesome icons in Wordpress CSS? The standard settings of "tiny, small, medium and such" are not giving me the control I need. I welcome any help.

Comment: Probably the selector you're using. Hard to tell without an example. Learn how to use Chrome or Firefox CSS inspector, you can manipulate your CSS live and it's very handy.

Comment: This is the page in the site being built -- the small icons to the left of the phone image are the ones Im asking about. I would need the icons larger but the circles to remain the same size.

http://192.254.210.212/~wallaceprinting/our-capabilities/

Comment: Browser Developer Tools is your friend :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFnDZ.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I researched those in Chrome DevTools, is that what I need to use for this or do I need a specific app to make the changes permanent? I would appreciate your thoughts -- and I am Mac OS.

Comment: Not sure if there's an app for that... what I do is to have the CSS file open and copy from Dev Tools onto it the changes that worked while live testing. Save CSS, reload page, test more... Looks like there are some [Chrome extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/css%20developer?hl=en&_category=extensions) for that